# Panel loses focus and scrollbar cannot be scrolled

Tags: c#, winforms, events, focus, panel

I have a main panel which includes 10 child panels. I wanted that always when my cursor enters the parent panel the scroll bar to be scrollable from mouse scroll.

I did this by adding ParentPanel.Focus() when mouse enters. Everything worked fine untill I saw that my textboxes from this child panels are unusable ( I cannot type in them) when my cursor leaves the child panel in which the textbox is. To go around this bug, I commented the ParentPanel.Focus() and the textbox worked fine. But again, I cannot scroll. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Code the TextBox's Enter event: textbox1.Focus(); ?

Comment: and do that for 20 TextBox's? isn't that too much?

Comment: Well, if it works, you can wire them all up dynamically&recursively to the same event and cast the sender to TextBox.. - But maybe catching the scrllUp&Down messages is an alternative..?

Answer (score 1):

`Panels` are not really good at having `Focus`.

This little helper function catches the `PageUp` and `PageDown` keys of all your `TextBoxes` and makes them scroll the outer `Panel`:

```
void hookUpTextBoxesIn(Control ctl, ScrollableControl sCtl)
{
    foreach( Control c in ctl.Controls)
    {
        if (c.Controls.Count > 0) hookUpTextBoxesIn(c, sCtl);
        if (c is TextBox)
        {
            c.PreviewKeyDown += (s, e) =>
                {
                    if (e.KeyData == Keys.PageDown) sCtl.AutoScrollPosition =
                        new Point(sCtl.AutoScrollPosition.X, 
                                 -sCtl.AutoScrollPosition.Y + 10);
                    if (e.KeyData == Keys.PageUp) sCtl.AutoScrollPosition =
                        new Point(sCtl.AutoScrollPosition.X,
                                 -sCtl.AutoScrollPosition.Y - 10);
                };
        }
    }
}
```

You would call it once in your setup like this:

```
hookUpTextBoxesIn(ParentPanel, ParentPanel);
```

In the `MouseEnter` you could write:

```
  if (!(ActiveControl is TextBox)) textBox1.Focus();
```

Change the scroll amount if you like.. I coded and tested it for vertical scrolling only. You may want to expand it for other keys or for advanced key combinations..

Comment: MouseEnter of the Parent Panel?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. But this really depends on the details of your layout: If the child Panels fill the Parent that won't do as you never could 'ebter' it.. Then all child Panels' MouseEnter would have to be used. They too can be hooked up to the same event.